Телеграм бот на Aiogram работает очень медленно
Написал бота,работает с API Trello. Пользователи с админкой в боте могут пополнять доски в трелло (назовем неким БД), а пользоавтели по нужным критериям могут найти нужные данные в Trello, также по API. Бот работает очень медленно. 1 сообщение получаю в ожидании 5-10 секунд. А там таких данных большие объемы
Конкретна эта часть работает долго
# Функция для отправки карточек Trello
async def send_trello_cards_page(message: types.Message,user_id: int, list_id: str, price_range: tuple, start_index: int = 0):
    url = f"https://api.trello.com/1/lists/{list_id}/cards"
    params = {
        "key": TRELLO_API_KEY,
        "token": TRELLO_API_TOKEN,
        "attachments": "true"
    }
    headers = {"Cookie": COOKIE}

    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        await message.answer("Не удалось получить данные с Trello.")
        return

    cards = response.json()
    if not cards:
        await message.answer("Список Trello пуст.")
        return

    # Сохраняем состояние пользователя при первом вызове
    if user_id not in user_states:
        user_states[user_id] = {
            "cards": cards,
            "index": 0
        }

    # Получаем отфильтрованные карточки
    filtered_cards = user_states[user_id].get("filtered_cards")
    if filtered_cards is None:  # Фильтруем карточки только один раз
        filtered_cards = [
            card for card in cards
            if price_range[0] <= extract_price_from_description(card.get('desc', '')) <= price_range[1]
        ]

        # Применяем фильтр по количеству комнат, если это не квартира
        current_rooms = user_filters[user_id].get("rooms", "1")
        property_type = user_filters[user_id].get("type", "apartment")  # Тип недвижимости

        if property_type != "apartment":
            if "и более" in current_rooms:
                min_rooms = int(current_rooms.split()[0])  # Извлекаем число перед "и более"
                filtered_cards = [
                    card for card in filtered_cards
                    if extract_rooms_from_description(card.get('desc', '') or '0').isdigit()
                    and int(extract_rooms_from_description(card.get('desc', ''))) >= min_rooms
                ]
            else:
                current_rooms_int = int(current_rooms)
                filtered_cards = [
                    card for card in filtered_cards
                    if extract_rooms_from_description(card.get('desc', '') or '0').isdigit()
                    and int(extract_rooms_from_description(card.get('desc', ''))) == current_rooms_int
                ]


        user_states[user_id]["filtered_cards"] = filtered_cards

    # Если отфильтрованных карточек нет, отправляем сообщение с предложением изменить фильтры
    if not filtered_cards:
        await message.answer(
            "По таким фильтрам нет объявлений. Попробуйте другие фильтры:",
            reply_markup=create_apartment_filters_inline(user_filters[user_id])  # Фильтры для квартиры
        )
        await message.answer(
            "Выберите действие:",
            reply_markup=create_search_keyboard()  # Обычная клавиатура для поиска
        )
        return

    # Отправляем карточки по 5 штук
    end_index = min(start_index + 5, len(filtered_cards))
    selected_cards = filtered_cards[start_index:end_index]

    for card in selected_cards:
        caption = f"{card['name']}\n{card.get('desc', 'Без описания')}"
        photos = []

        for attachment in card.get('attachments', []):
            if attachment.get('isUpload') and attachment['url'].endswith(('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png')):
                image_path = download_image_in_memory(attachment['url'], headers)
                if image_path:
                    if not photos:
                        photos.append(InputMediaPhoto(InputFile(image_path), caption=caption))
                    else:
                        photos.append(InputMediaPhoto(InputFile(image_path)))

        if photos:
            if len(photos) >= 1:
                await message.answer_media_group(media=photos)
            else:
                await message.answer_photo(photo=photos[0].media, caption=photos[0].caption)

    # Обновляем текущий индекс
    user_states[user_id]["index"] = end_index

    # Проверяем, есть ли еще карточки
    total_cards = len(filtered_cards)
    remaining = total_cards - end_index

    if remaining > 0:
        next_count = min(5, remaining)
        await message.answer(
            f"Мы отправили вам {end_index} объявлений из {total_cards}. Отправить еще {next_count}?",
            reply_markup=create_continue_keyboard()
        )
    else:
        await message.answer("Все объявления отправлены.")
        user_states.pop(user_id, None)
        # Полная очистка данных пользователя из user_states
        if user_id in user_states:
            del user_states[user_id]  # Удаляем все данные пользователя


# Функция для извлечения количества комнат из описания карточки
def extract_rooms_from_description(description: str) -> str:
    # Список ключевых фраз для поиска
    patterns = [
        r'Комнат:\s*(\d+)',          # Ищем "Комнат: X"
        r'Комнаты:\s*(\d+)',         # Ищем "Комнаты: X"
        r'Количество комнат:\s*(\d+)' # Ищем "Количество комнат: X"
    ]

    for pattern in patterns:
        match = re.search(pattern, description)
        if match:  # Если нашли совпадение
            return match.group(1)
    
    # Если ничего не найдено, возвращаем значение по умолчанию
    return "1"


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Попробуйте логировать все действия, чтобы понять - что именно тормозит. Или именно получение ботом сообщения от пользователя тормозит? Пользователей при этом много одновременно или один? Сообщение текстовое или с медиа? В общем, полностью сценарий распишите и проанализируйте. Тогда можно будет что-то обсуждать. И хотя бы костяк бота покажите в вопросе, только токен не забудьте удалить.

@CrazyElf Бот на 1100 строк вышел.. я бы показал в ином случае. Да, медиа используется. Вообще бот сначала получает список карточек с Трелло, заем ищет в описании нужне строки. А именно количество комнат, Цена. и только потом отправляет пользователю. Пользователь 1-2. не знаю что будет в масштабах 20-30 человек. Может стоит БД сменить

И всё-таки. Что именно тормозит? Весь процесс занимает 5-10 секунд? Логируйте, чтобы понять, что в какой момент происходит и сколько занимает какое действие. Гадательной оптимизацией можно заниматься вечно. Можете, конечно, пробовать переезжать на другую базу и т.д., только не факт, что дело в этом. Сначала нужно определить, какие конкретно этапы у вас тормозят, и только потом оптимизировать как-то именно эти этапы, а не хвататься за всё подряд.

в момент получения данных с трелло и отправки их пользователю. то есть во время формифроания сообщения (Альбома фотографий, добавления описания)

Ну вот и приведите в вопросе те фрагменты кода, которые долго работают и напишите, сколько именно они работают. Тогда можно рассчитывать на какие-то советы. Сейчас текст вопроса слишком не конкретный.

@CrazyElf исправил код

А вот эти загрузки download_image_in_memory(attachment['url'], headers) они тоже с Trello? Может они тормозят? Вам обязательно эти картинки скачивать и через телегу отправлять? Подозреваю, что если этих картинок много, то тормозить сразу много где будет. И скачка этих картинок, и отправка их в телегу, и потом скачка их пользователем из телеги. Там всегда разные картинки, а то может их как-то кешировать попробовать?

@CrazyElf Да, скачивает вложения с карточки trello. в основном это фото объектов недвижки. так что да, действие обязательно, фотографии в формате jpeg

Причем еще пока бот не ответит одному пользовател, он на другого не переключается. хотя использую async def

Ну так у вас не весь код асинхронный. Например, весь кусок со скачкой картинок синхронный. Если в асинхронную функцию попадёт управление, то оно не вернётся оттуда до следующего await. Переписывайте код на асинхронный. Например, тот же кусок со скачкой картинок в цикле.

@CrazyElf равзе async def не вызывается асинхронно?

Вам нужно почитать, что такое асинхронность, и как она работает. Про потоки, машину состояний и т.п. Пока вы не ожидаете ничего в вашем асинхронном коде через await, почти никаких преимуществ от async def у вас нет. Вы занимаете поток синхронным выполнением большого куска кода, а этих потоков либо мало, либо он вообще один, вот другие пользователи и не обрабатываются. Асинхронность - штука не автоматическая, её нужно уметь "готовить".

@CrazyElf не знаю как отметить ваш комментарий полезным. спасибо большое

Ну вы главное разберитесь. Если всё получится, можете сами на свой вопрос ответ оформить, описав решение в общих чертах хотя бы. Может кому-то ещё поможет.

Получилось значительно ускорить выполенение кода ботом. Тестировал с 5 утройств, все заработало в разы лучше. Оптимизировать код получилось благодаря корректному изменению Асинхронных функций, и изменению response = requests.get(url, params=params) на async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: async with session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers) as response:
